# Array is printing char elements instead of int elements

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create an array of int elements, however its giving me char elements. whats going on?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment5a {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int x[] = new int[1500];
        //create an array of numbers 2 to 1500
        for (int i=2; i<15; i++){
            x[i] = i;
        }

        System.out.println(x);
```

this is what I have. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean?  `new int[1500]` will give you an array of `int` -- it's impossible for it to do anything else.

Comment: System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x)) ?

Comment: According to **your** code `x` is an array. What do you expect `System.out.println(x);` to produce.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, I'm new to Java and used to Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you simply write `System.out.println(*array*)`, the command will print the location in memory that stores the array.

If you are looking to print out the value stored in the array, you must specify the array index value you wish to print (note: array indexes begin at `0` and end at `size-1`):

```
System.out.println(x[position]);
```

If you wish to print out the characters to the entire array, you must either use a `for-loop` or an `enhanced for-loop`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    System.out.println(x[i]);
}
```

The above code will create an `int i` which acts as an index for the array. Every time the loop runs, the value stored at position `i` will be printed out from the array `x[]`. `x.length` is used to make sure that `int i` does not exceed the array size limit.

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to print out the array itself, which behaves as `Object` when printed. You have to do

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
```

if you want to print out the whole array, or

```
System.out.println(x[0]);
```

to get a single element.